# android scala and eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, scala

I tried following the instructions here [link text](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Developing_for_Android) to make a scala application. However when I run the "ant install" command I get the following error

```
aaptexec doesn't support the "basename" attribute
```

I read this is because of the new sdk 7 version [here](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Can-t-compile-Scala-for-Android-SDK-Tools-revision-7-td2534044.html).  However noone on that thread seems to offer any solution.

Has anyone tried to do this with the new sdk?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [Building Android apps in Scala with sbt](http://zegoggl.es/2009/12/building-android-apps-in-scala-with-sbt.html), I found it is much easier to use SBT to build Scala/Andoird application than Eclipse.

You should also use https://github.com/steve918/android-plugin instead of the plug-in describe at the page if you want use latest Android SDK.

Comment: I've seen that alternative before but I don't feel confortable not using an IDE. Also how do you debug without eclipse?

Comment: If you are not comfortable not using IDE, I afraid there is not much options and harder to start. The SBT one is the most easy/convenient solution I have seen so far for developing Android using Scala. And even without Eclipse, you still could debug using a lot of tools like adb or ddms.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/treeshaker/ may be what you're looking for.

It's a build step for Eclipse which, used together with Scala IDE, will enable you to use Scala on Android.

Comment: I just went through a few different Scala/Android/Eclipse paths, and Treeshaker was the only one to work as given.   It had the fewest dependencies, didn't care I'm using the 2.9 plugin, and had the simplest installation.

Comment: Hmmm, scratch that.  Turns out to STOP working with 2.9 after a few builds.  https://groups.google.com/group/scala-on-android/browse_thread/thread/2dff7f72335bf3d7   Alas.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here to use the latest Android SDK, with Eclipse 3.7.2 and Scala 2.9 :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11084146/1287856

- It compiles under Android SDK 18
- It does not have the strange side-effects of Treeshaker like forgetting to include some classes.