# Build Android project using AndroidProguardScala with Ant

Tags: android, scala, ant, build

i'm developing for Android in Scala following instructions from [Eclipse, Android, Scala made easy but still does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924015/eclipse-android-scala-made-easy-but-still-does-not-work/11084146#11084146). Everything works great in my development machine, building within Eclipse.

But now i need to build the project with Ant, outside of Eclipse, and i'm lost.

I still want to use this method, don't want to use SBT. So i'm assuming i should do a "headless build" of the plugin... any hint?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't/won't use SBT?

Answer (score 0):

You really should try and use SBT. There is a great plugin for sbt on [github](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/) with a good getting started tutorial. Also, SBT's [wiki](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/) has some really good information for how to go beyond the basic sbt.

The sbt-android plugin has a really nice feature where it adds Typed Resources to your android build so you can do something like:

```
var button:Button = activity.findView(TR.myButtonInTheLayout)
```

Type safe layout management... its a pretty handy feature.

Sbt-android also supports using standard scala directory layout or standard android directory layout, whatever your comfortable with.

Comment: I wouldn't be the only one working with the project, so the idea is to use the same Eclipse environment every Android dev is used to (with the bonus of coding in Scala).

Comment: Like you said, your already building in eclipse but can't get ant to work correctly.  Why not use SBT instead of ANT?