# Unable to set breakpoints in scala 2.10 RC3 Android and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, scala, breakpoints

I was developping using Scala, and the AndroidProguardScala plugin with the following mode:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11084146/1287856

I upgraded my Android project from older versions of scala to a newer one, namely 2.10.0-RC3 with their [awesome new IDE plugin](http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html#scala_ide_21_milestone_2) :

I found myself unable to set breakpoints in my scala files by clicking on the column to the left of each file.

Fortunately, I found a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround I just found for that was to change the order in which libraries are imported:

- Right-click on the project, select `properties`
- Tab `Java build path`, `Order and export`
- Make sure "Scala library [2.10.0-RC3]' is on the top
- Clean the project, rebuild, now you can set breakpoints as before.